# Cannot import cython module which is generated using setup.py

Tags: python-3.x, cython

I have converted a .pyx file to .pyd using cpython setup.py method but always get the following message :

```
ValueError: no signature found for builtin <built-in function hello>
```

The file I am converting test.pyx :

```
from pyxll import xl_func
@xl_func
def hello():
    return "HELLO WORLD"
```

setup.py script :

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension("example.test", sources=["example/test.pyx"])
]
setup(
    name='Example',
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules=ext_modules
)
```

When I try to import this test module I get the specified message.
Although when I tried to convert test.pyx without import and decorator it worked so is there any specific configuration change required in setup to include pyxll.

> Enviorment : Python 3.8.5 32 bit

Comment: What did you put in the pxd file? In addition, your function is python code that is being statically compiled; why?

Comment: by pxd you mean pyx file ??

Comment: You say `I have converted a .pyx file to .pyd using cpython setup.py method`. Cython uses a `pxd` file for definitions and `pyx` files for implementation (you can also use `.py` in so-called `pure-mode` but that is a different story). A `pyd` file however is not used by cython.

Comment: @cvanelteren thank you for the info I was'nt aware of that .... since you said .py works I tried it and it worked.

Comment: Keep in mind that is not the preferred way in python. A `py` with `pxd` file is called pure mode, see here https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pure.html.

Answer (score 0):

As @cvanelteren pointed out file type was the problem I compiled a py file and it fixed the issue of imports